# If $G$ is abelian and ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is finite, prove that $G$ has finite torsion subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, automorphism-group, torsion-groups

This is **Exercise 4.3.10** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7B%5Crm%20Aut%7D(G)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Afinite%2C%20OR%20content%3Atorsion%2C%20OR%20content%3Aabelian&p=10) and [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5BAutomorphism-group%5D+finite+torsion+group+), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

The *torsion-subgroup* of an abelian group $G$ is the subgroup of all elements of $G$ of finite order.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group such that ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is finite, prove that $G$ has finite torsion-subgroup.

### Thoughts:

Let $G$ be as defined above and $\varphi\in{\rm Aut}(G)$.

I think that, because $\lvert \varphi (x)\rvert=\lvert x\rvert$, and there are only finitely many permutations of elements of a given order due to $\lvert{\rm Aut}(G)\rvert<\infty$, there must exist only finitely many elements of finite order.

However, I doubt this is as simple as that, and even if the idea is right, I'm not sure how to make the proof more rigorous.

Something tells me I'm missing something . . .

Please help :)

Comment: This was proved in : R. Baer, Finite extensions of abelian groups with minimum condition, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 79 (1955), 521-540. Franciosi also mentions it [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/BA1717E176C4D230C9C55EF099D185F9/S0017089500006911a.pdf/some_finiteness_conditions_for_automorphism_groups.pdf) in the introduction, with a generalisation proved in $[6]$.

Comment: Those results seem to be much stronger than what is asked here, since they apply to not-necessarily-abelian groups. Presumably, this textbook exercise can be solved using more elementary means.

Comment: this paper cites a place where it's proven https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869383900200 . However I can't find the cited document :/

Comment: Re: your paragraph beginning with "I think that," note that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite and torsion but only has finitely many elements of each order.

Comment: I didn't know ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$ is finite, @NoahSchweber. I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments, everyone :)

Comment: Aut$(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ isn't finite, and @NoahSchweber didn't say that it is.

Comment: Thank you, @AndreasBlass. I thought he was offering a counterexample (to my attempt) . . .